# SMART tests show rapidly oscillating Hardware ECC Recovered value

Tags: 14.04, hard-drive, smart

I have been subjected to an unholy amount of pain from my desktop tonight, including the near-loss of data due to corruption (in the /tmp directory !?) on one disk and erratic behavior from the other disk.

One disk is used for file storage, and the other is used solely for swap space. The swap space HDD (40gb) gave me this response (at bottom) after running `sudo smartctl --all /dev/sda`.

---

The issues that I was suspicious of were the value for Hardware ECC Recovered (which has been fluctuating from the high 10000s up to the high 40000s very rapidly recently):

```
ID# ATTRIBUTE_NAME          FLAG     VALUE WORST THRESH TYPE      UPDATED  WHEN_FAILED RAW_VALUE
195 Hardware_ECC_Recovered  0x000a   252   251   000    Old_age   Always       -       41212
```

And these errors:

```
SMART Error Log Version: 1
Warning: ATA error count 31 inconsistent with error log pointer 5

ATA Error Count: 31 (device log contains only the most recent five errors)
    CR = Command Register [HEX]
    FR = Features Register [HEX]
    SC = Sector Count Register [HEX]
    SN = Sector Number Register [HEX]
    CL = Cylinder Low Register [HEX]
    CH = Cylinder High Register [HEX]
    DH = Device/Head Register [HEX]
    DC = Device Command Register [HEX]
    ER = Error register [HEX]
    ST = Status register [HEX]
Powered_Up_Time is measured from power on, and printed as
DDd+hh:mm:SS.sss where DD=days, hh=hours, mm=minutes,
SS=sec, and sss=millisec. It "wraps" after 49.710 days.

Error 31 occurred at disk power-on lifetime: 38693 hours (1612 days + 5 hours)
  When the command that caused the error occurred, the device was in an unknown state.

  After command completion occurred, registers were:
  ER ST SC SN CL CH DH
  -- -- -- -- -- -- --
  01 51 04 6c d7 72 e1  Error: AMNF 4 sectors at LBA = 0x0172d76c = 24303468

  Commands leading to the command that caused the error were:
  CR FR SC SN CL CH DH DC   Powered_Up_Time  Command/Feature_Name
  -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --  ----------------  --------------------
  c8 00 04 6c d7 72 e1 08      00:23:02.400  READ DMA
  f8 00 00 00 00 00 e0 08      00:23:02.400  READ NATIVE MAX ADDRESS [OBS-ACS-3]
  ec 00 00 00 00 00 a0 0a      00:23:02.384  IDENTIFY DEVICE
  ef 03 45 00 00 00 a0 0a      00:23:02.368  SET FEATURES [Set transfer mode]
  f8 00 00 00 00 00 e0 08      00:23:02.368  READ NATIVE MAX ADDRESS [OBS-ACS-3]

Error 30 occurred at disk power-on lifetime: 38693 hours (1612 days + 5 hours)
  When the command that caused the error occurred, the device was in an unknown state.

  After command completion occurred, registers were:
  ER ST SC SN CL CH DH
  -- -- -- -- -- -- --
  40 51 04 6c d7 72 e1  Error: UNC 4 sectors at LBA = 0x0172d76c = 24303468

  Commands leading to the command that caused the error were:
  CR FR SC SN CL CH DH DC   Powered_Up_Time  Command/Feature_Name
  -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --  ----------------  --------------------
  c8 00 04 6c d7 72 e1 08      00:23:01.072  READ DMA
  f8 00 00 00 00 00 e0 08      00:23:01.056  READ NATIVE MAX ADDRESS [OBS-ACS-3]
  ec 00 00 00 00 00 a0 0a      00:23:01.040  IDENTIFY DEVICE
  ef 03 45 00 00 00 a0 0a      00:23:01.024  SET FEATURES [Set transfer mode]
  f8 00 00 00 00 00 e0 08      00:23:01.024  READ NATIVE MAX ADDRESS [OBS-ACS-3]

Error 29 occurred at disk power-on lifetime: 38693 hours (1612 days + 5 hours)
  When the command that caused the error occurred, the device was in an unknown state.

  After command completion occurred, registers were:
  ER ST SC SN CL CH DH
  -- -- -- -- -- -- --
  40 51 04 6c d7 72 e1  Error: UNC 4 sectors at LBA = 0x0172d76c = 24303468

  Commands leading to the command that caused the error were:
  CR FR SC SN CL CH DH DC   Powered_Up_Time  Command/Feature_Name
  -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --  ----------------  --------------------
  c8 00 04 6c d7 72 e1 08      00:22:59.728  READ DMA
  f8 00 00 00 00 00 e0 08      00:22:59.712  READ NATIVE MAX ADDRESS [OBS-ACS-3]
  ec 00 00 00 00 00 a0 0a      00:22:59.696  IDENTIFY DEVICE
  ef 03 45 00 00 00 a0 0a      00:22:59.680  SET FEATURES [Set transfer mode]
  f8 00 00 00 00 00 e0 08      00:22:59.680  READ NATIVE MAX ADDRESS [OBS-ACS-3]

Error 28 occurred at disk power-on lifetime: 38693 hours (1612 days + 5 hours)
  When the command that caused the error occurred, the device was in an unknown state.

  After command completion occurred, registers were:
  ER ST SC SN CL CH DH
  -- -- -- -- -- -- --
  01 51 04 6c d7 72 e1  Error: AMNF 4 sectors at LBA = 0x0172d76c = 24303468

  Commands leading to the command that caused the error were:
  CR FR SC SN CL CH DH DC   Powered_Up_Time  Command/Feature_Name
  -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --  ----------------  --------------------
  c8 00 04 6c d7 72 e1 08      00:22:58.576  READ DMA
  f8 00 00 00 00 00 e0 08      00:22:58.560  READ NATIVE MAX ADDRESS [OBS-ACS-3]
  ec 00 00 00 00 00 a0 0a      00:22:58.544  IDENTIFY DEVICE
  ef 03 45 00 00 00 a0 0a      00:22:58.528  SET FEATURES [Set transfer mode]
  f8 00 00 00 00 00 e0 08      00:22:58.528  READ NATIVE MAX ADDRESS [OBS-ACS-3]

Error 27 occurred at disk power-on lifetime: 38693 hours (1612 days + 5 hours)
  When the command that caused the error occurred, the device was in an unknown state.

  After command completion occurred, registers were:
  ER ST SC SN CL CH DH
  -- -- -- -- -- -- --
  40 51 04 6c d7 72 e1  Error: UNC 4 sectors at LBA = 0x0172d76c = 24303468

  Commands leading to the command that caused the error were:
  CR FR SC SN CL CH DH DC   Powered_Up_Time  Command/Feature_Name
  -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --  ----------------  --------------------
  c8 00 04 6c d7 72 e1 08      00:22:57.232  READ DMA
  f8 00 00 00 00 00 e0 08      00:22:57.216  READ NATIVE MAX ADDRESS [OBS-ACS-3]
  ec 00 00 00 00 00 a0 0a      00:22:57.200  IDENTIFY DEVICE
  ef 03 45 00 00 00 a0 0a      00:22:57.184  SET FEATURES [Set transfer mode]
  f8 00 00 00 00 00 e0 08      00:22:57.184  READ NATIVE MAX ADDRESS [OBS-ACS-3]

SMART Self-test log structure revision number 1
No self-tests have been logged.  [To run self-tests, use: smartctl -t]
```

**Bottom line, I don't know whether to replace the drive or not. Please help me figure out if I should replace it, and why I should replace it. Thanks so much.**

---

Actual output:

```
smartctl 6.2 2013-07-26 r3841 [i686-linux-3.13.0-24-generic] (local build)
Copyright (C) 2002-13, Bruce Allen, Christian Franke, www.smartmontools.org

=== START OF INFORMATION SECTION ===
Model Family:     Maxtor DiamondMax Plus 8
Device Model:     Maxtor 6E040L0
Serial Number:    E17ZAE3E
Firmware Version: NAR61590
User Capacity:    40,016,019,456 bytes [40.0 GB]
Sector Size:      512 bytes logical/physical
Device is:        In smartctl database [for details use: -P show]
ATA Version is:   ATA/ATAPI-7 T13/1532D revision 0
Local Time is:    Wed Jul  2 01:27:30 2014 MDT
SMART support is: Available - device has SMART capability.
SMART support is: Enabled

=== START OF READ SMART DATA SECTION ===
SMART overall-health self-assessment test result: PASSED

General SMART Values:
Offline data collection status:  (0x82) Offline data collection activity
                    was completed without error.
                    Auto Offline Data Collection: Enabled.
Self-test execution status:      (   0) The previous self-test routine completed
                    without error or no self-test has ever 
                    been run.
Total time to complete Offline 
data collection:        ( 1021) seconds.
Offline data collection
capabilities:            (0x5b) SMART execute Offline immediate.
                    Auto Offline data collection on/off support.
                    Suspend Offline collection upon new
                    command.
                    Offline surface scan supported.
                    Self-test supported.
                    No Conveyance Self-test supported.
                    Selective Self-test supported.
SMART capabilities:            (0x0003) Saves SMART data before entering
                    power-saving mode.
                    Supports SMART auto save timer.
Error logging capability:        (0x01) Error logging supported.
                    No General Purpose Logging support.
Short self-test routine 
recommended polling time:    (   2) minutes.
Extended self-test routine
recommended polling time:    (  17) minutes.

SMART Attributes Data Structure revision number: 16
Vendor Specific SMART Attributes with Thresholds:
ID# ATTRIBUTE_NAME          FLAG     VALUE WORST THRESH TYPE      UPDATED  WHEN_FAILED RAW_VALUE
  3 Spin_Up_Time            0x0027   234   221   063    Pre-fail  Always       -       5949
  4 Start_Stop_Count        0x0032   250   250   000    Old_age   Always       -       7874
  5 Reallocated_Sector_Ct   0x0033   253   253   063    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
  6 Read_Channel_Margin     0x0001   253   253   100    Pre-fail  Offline      -       0
  7 Seek_Error_Rate         0x000a   253   252   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
  8 Seek_Time_Performance   0x0027   253   239   187    Pre-fail  Always       -       50786
  9 Power_On_Minutes        0x0032   130   130   000    Old_age   Always       -       148h+23m
 10 Spin_Retry_Count        0x002b   253   247   157    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
 11 Calibration_Retry_Count 0x002b   253   252   223    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
 12 Power_Cycle_Count       0x0032   248   248   000    Old_age   Always       -       2041
192 Power-Off_Retract_Count 0x0032   252   252   000    Old_age   Always       -       1406
193 Load_Cycle_Count        0x0032   251   251   000    Old_age   Always       -       10723
194 Temperature_Celsius     0x0032   253   253   000    Old_age   Always       -       39
195 Hardware_ECC_Recovered  0x000a   252   251   000    Old_age   Always       -       41212
196 Reallocated_Event_Count 0x0008   253   253   000    Old_age   Offline      -       0
197 Current_Pending_Sector  0x0008   253   253   000    Old_age   Offline      -       0
198 Offline_Uncorrectable   0x0008   253   253   000    Old_age   Offline      -       0
199 UDMA_CRC_Error_Count    0x0008   199   199   000    Old_age   Offline      -       0
200 Multi_Zone_Error_Rate   0x000a   253   252   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
201 Soft_Read_Error_Rate    0x000a   253   250   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
202 Data_Address_Mark_Errs  0x000a   253   252   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
203 Run_Out_Cancel          0x000b   253   252   180    Pre-fail  Always       -       1
204 Soft_ECC_Correction     0x000a   253   252   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
205 Thermal_Asperity_Rate   0x000a   253   252   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
207 Spin_High_Current       0x002a   253   247   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
208 Spin_Buzz               0x002a   253   252   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
209 Offline_Seek_Performnce 0x0024   184   183   000    Old_age   Offline      -       0
 99 Unknown_Attribute       0x0004   253   253   000    Old_age   Offline      -       0
100 Unknown_Attribute       0x0004   253   253   000    Old_age   Offline      -       0
101 Unknown_Attribute       0x0004   253   253   000    Old_age   Offline      -       0

SMART Error Log Version: 1
Warning: ATA error count 31 inconsistent with error log pointer 5

ATA Error Count: 31 (device log contains only the most recent five errors)
    CR = Command Register [HEX]
    FR = Features Register [HEX]
    SC = Sector Count Register [HEX]
    SN = Sector Number Register [HEX]
    CL = Cylinder Low Register [HEX]
    CH = Cylinder High Register [HEX]
    DH = Device/Head Register [HEX]
    DC = Device Command Register [HEX]
    ER = Error register [HEX]
    ST = Status register [HEX]
Powered_Up_Time is measured from power on, and printed as
DDd+hh:mm:SS.sss where DD=days, hh=hours, mm=minutes,
SS=sec, and sss=millisec. It "wraps" after 49.710 days.

Error 31 occurred at disk power-on lifetime: 38693 hours (1612 days + 5 hours)
  When the command that caused the error occurred, the device was in an unknown state.

  After command completion occurred, registers were:
  ER ST SC SN CL CH DH
  -- -- -- -- -- -- --
  01 51 04 6c d7 72 e1  Error: AMNF 4 sectors at LBA = 0x0172d76c = 24303468

  Commands leading to the command that caused the error were:
  CR FR SC SN CL CH DH DC   Powered_Up_Time  Command/Feature_Name
  -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --  ----------------  --------------------
  c8 00 04 6c d7 72 e1 08      00:23:02.400  READ DMA
  f8 00 00 00 00 00 e0 08      00:23:02.400  READ NATIVE MAX ADDRESS [OBS-ACS-3]
  ec 00 00 00 00 00 a0 0a      00:23:02.384  IDENTIFY DEVICE
  ef 03 45 00 00 00 a0 0a      00:23:02.368  SET FEATURES [Set transfer mode]
  f8 00 00 00 00 00 e0 08      00:23:02.368  READ NATIVE MAX ADDRESS [OBS-ACS-3]

Error 30 occurred at disk power-on lifetime: 38693 hours (1612 days + 5 hours)
  When the command that caused the error occurred, the device was in an unknown state.

  After command completion occurred, registers were:
  ER ST SC SN CL CH DH
  -- -- -- -- -- -- --
  40 51 04 6c d7 72 e1  Error: UNC 4 sectors at LBA = 0x0172d76c = 24303468

  Commands leading to the command that caused the error were:
  CR FR SC SN CL CH DH DC   Powered_Up_Time  Command/Feature_Name
  -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --  ----------------  --------------------
  c8 00 04 6c d7 72 e1 08      00:23:01.072  READ DMA
  f8 00 00 00 00 00 e0 08      00:23:01.056  READ NATIVE MAX ADDRESS [OBS-ACS-3]
  ec 00 00 00 00 00 a0 0a      00:23:01.040  IDENTIFY DEVICE
  ef 03 45 00 00 00 a0 0a      00:23:01.024  SET FEATURES [Set transfer mode]
  f8 00 00 00 00 00 e0 08      00:23:01.024  READ NATIVE MAX ADDRESS [OBS-ACS-3]

Error 29 occurred at disk power-on lifetime: 38693 hours (1612 days + 5 hours)
  When the command that caused the error occurred, the device was in an unknown state.

  After command completion occurred, registers were:
  ER ST SC SN CL CH DH
  -- -- -- -- -- -- --
  40 51 04 6c d7 72 e1  Error: UNC 4 sectors at LBA = 0x0172d76c = 24303468

  Commands leading to the command that caused the error were:
  CR FR SC SN CL CH DH DC   Powered_Up_Time  Command/Feature_Name
  -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --  ----------------  --------------------
  c8 00 04 6c d7 72 e1 08      00:22:59.728  READ DMA
  f8 00 00 00 00 00 e0 08      00:22:59.712  READ NATIVE MAX ADDRESS [OBS-ACS-3]
  ec 00 00 00 00 00 a0 0a      00:22:59.696  IDENTIFY DEVICE
  ef 03 45 00 00 00 a0 0a      00:22:59.680  SET FEATURES [Set transfer mode]
  f8 00 00 00 00 00 e0 08      00:22:59.680  READ NATIVE MAX ADDRESS [OBS-ACS-3]

Error 28 occurred at disk power-on lifetime: 38693 hours (1612 days + 5 hours)
  When the command that caused the error occurred, the device was in an unknown state.

  After command completion occurred, registers were:
  ER ST SC SN CL CH DH
  -- -- -- -- -- -- --
  01 51 04 6c d7 72 e1  Error: AMNF 4 sectors at LBA = 0x0172d76c = 24303468

  Commands leading to the command that caused the error were:
  CR FR SC SN CL CH DH DC   Powered_Up_Time  Command/Feature_Name
  -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --  ----------------  --------------------
  c8 00 04 6c d7 72 e1 08      00:22:58.576  READ DMA
  f8 00 00 00 00 00 e0 08      00:22:58.560  READ NATIVE MAX ADDRESS [OBS-ACS-3]
  ec 00 00 00 00 00 a0 0a      00:22:58.544  IDENTIFY DEVICE
  ef 03 45 00 00 00 a0 0a      00:22:58.528  SET FEATURES [Set transfer mode]
  f8 00 00 00 00 00 e0 08      00:22:58.528  READ NATIVE MAX ADDRESS [OBS-ACS-3]

Error 27 occurred at disk power-on lifetime: 38693 hours (1612 days + 5 hours)
  When the command that caused the error occurred, the device was in an unknown state.

  After command completion occurred, registers were:
  ER ST SC SN CL CH DH
  -- -- -- -- -- -- --
  40 51 04 6c d7 72 e1  Error: UNC 4 sectors at LBA = 0x0172d76c = 24303468

  Commands leading to the command that caused the error were:
  CR FR SC SN CL CH DH DC   Powered_Up_Time  Command/Feature_Name
  -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --  ----------------  --------------------
  c8 00 04 6c d7 72 e1 08      00:22:57.232  READ DMA
  f8 00 00 00 00 00 e0 08      00:22:57.216  READ NATIVE MAX ADDRESS [OBS-ACS-3]
  ec 00 00 00 00 00 a0 0a      00:22:57.200  IDENTIFY DEVICE
  ef 03 45 00 00 00 a0 0a      00:22:57.184  SET FEATURES [Set transfer mode]
  f8 00 00 00 00 00 e0 08      00:22:57.184  READ NATIVE MAX ADDRESS [OBS-ACS-3]

SMART Self-test log structure revision number 1
No self-tests have been logged.  [To run self-tests, use: smartctl -t]


SMART Selective self-test log data structure revision number 1
 SPAN  MIN_LBA  MAX_LBA  CURRENT_TEST_STATUS
    1        0        0  Not_testing
    2        0        0  Not_testing
    3        0        0  Not_testing
    4        0        0  Not_testing
    5        0        0  Not_testing
Selective self-test flags (0x0):
  After scanning selected spans, do NOT read-scan remainder of disk.
If Selective self-test is pending on power-up, resume after 0 minute delay.
```

Answer (score 1):

From https://kb.acronis.com/content/9131:

```
Hardware ECC Recovered S.M.A.R.T. parameter indicates time between ECC-corrected errors.
```

It doesn't seem surprising that the raw value would jump around a bit.